# Unable to increase heap size for JMeter on Mac OSX

Tags: java, macos, jmeter, heap-memory

Is there a way to increase heap size of JMeter in Mac OSX? I have tried editing the `jmeter.bat` file, but it didn't help.

I edited the `jmeter.sh` file to add `JVM_ARGS="-Xms3072m -Xmx3072m" jmeter.sh`

I tried the following also

```
#!/bin/bash

heap_size='3072m'
JAVA_CMD="java -Xms$heap_size -Xmx$heap_size" meter`
```

as suggested in this link [increase the memory allocated to jmeter in ubuntu linux](http://www.mcdruid.co.uk/content/increase-the-memory-allocated-to-jmeter-in-ubuntu-linux)

Does any one know how to do it in Mac OSX. I have java version as follows:

```
java version 1.6.0_65
Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 1.6.0_65-b14-462-11M4609)
Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (build 20.65-b04-462, mixed mode)`
```

on OSX 10.9.4

Answer (score 7, accepted):

As per [JMeter Performance and Tuning Tips](http://blazemeter.com/blog/jmeter-performance-and-tuning-tips)

> Default JMeter java configuration comes with 512 Mo and very little GC tuning.
>   First ensure you set -Xmx option value to a reasonable value regarding your test requirements.
>   Then change MaxNewSize option in jmeter file to respect the original ratio between MaxNewSize and -Xmx.

Java Virtual Machine parameters can be tuned in `jmeter` script file which lives under /bin folder of JMeter installation. So

1. Open `jmeter` script with text editor of your choice
2. Look for the line `HEAP="-Xms512m -Xmx512m"`
3. Change minimum and maximum values according to your desires
4. Save the file and make sure that you're executing `jmeter`, not `jmeter.sh`

If you're looking for once-only command-line JVM args overriding you can call JMeter main jar directly without any shell script wrappers as

```
java -Xms1G -Xmx3G -jar ApacheJMeter.jar
```

The command above assumes that you're invoking it from /bin folder of your JMeter installation.

Comment: Thanks it did increase the performance of Jmeter but the memory utilized still seems go max upto 800MBs on the activity monitor. Still throws out of memory error. I am novice with Jmeter so please advice - Is 5 requests per second for overall 10,000 requests too much if i am allocating `java -Xms2G -Xmx4G -jar ApacheJMeter.jar` i.e. max 4G memory for a system with 16G memory/Quad core proc. Thanks!

Comment: update your JRE to 1.7., this should solve the problem.

Comment: @JmeterPerfTest Thanks i upgraded java to 1.8 and the memory being utilized or seems to be is now upto 1.5 GB on activity monitor even though i have setup the min as 2GB and max as 4GB. Still max tests i can run it seems is for 2000 requests at one go @ 5 requests per second to avoid the out of memory error.

Comment: Can you provide some details about the scenario you are testing.

Comment: @JmeterPerfTest hey i missed your comment i think. Let me know what details you need. I am testing my web services that perform db transactions. I observed i can only run max 2000 users with single jmeter installation to avoid out of memory error. otherwise based on the requirement the jmeter service utilizes memory as required ~ upto 1.5G to 3G as i was able to see. and number of requests per second depend on how much load my web service can take before it starts rejecting connections.

Answer (score 1):

I installed JMeter on my Mac via Homebrew and found that I needed to create a new `setenv.sh` file containing the configurations, as specified in the `jmeter` file instructions:

> ### Do not set the variables in this script. Instead put them into a script
>
> ### setenv.sh in JMETER_HOME/bin to keep your customisations separate.

I found that the JMETER_HOME path was `/usr/local/Cellar/jmeter/5.4.3/libexec/` as opposed to `/usr/local/Cellar/jmeter/5.4.3/` which I initially tried unsuccessfully.

So, in the end, I had
`/usr/local/Cellar/jmeter/5.4.3/libexec/bin/setenv.sh` conatining:

```
HEAP="-Xms2g -Xmx4g -XX:MaxMetaspaceSize=512m"
NEW="-XX:NewSize=512m -XX:MaxNewSize=1024m"
```

Which I verified was working from the following in the `jmeter.log` file:

```
INFO o.a.j.JMeter: Max memory     =4294967296
```