# How to set the -Xmx for JRE when start running JMeter

Tags: java, jmeter, performance-testing, java-server

When running JMeter, java server has the -Xmx value of only 512 MB. I tried to change it via following code in the jmeter.bat.sh file.

```
set HEAP=-server -Xms512m -Xmx6144m
```

set NEW=-XX:NewSize=512m -XX:MaxNewSize=6144m

also tried this:

```
set HEAP= -Xms512m -Xmx6144m
```

set NEW=-XX:NewSize=512m -XX:MaxNewSize=6144m

By checking the process after while JMeter is running I can see that java -sever doesn't recognize this setting.

Comment: Are you using jmeter 3.2?

Comment: I'm using Jmeter 3.1

Comment: Have you read https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6450132/java-seems-to-ignore-xms-and-xmx-options?

Comment: yep, but when I run my jmeter command, the java sever get's started by jmeter I guess. So I can't actually pass another parameter to it, or is there a way?

Comment: check below links for detailed info; 

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34160452/increase-memory-for-jmeter-on-command-line

https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/9-easy-solutions-jmeter-load-test-%E2%80%9Cout-memory%E2%80%9D-failure

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34160452/increase-memory-for-jmeter-on-command-line

Comment: that was really helpful, thank you.
but know the virtual memory gets blown up to 10GB, and even if I kill the PID it still starts from the same level the last JMeter test finished.

Comment: there's `jmeter`, `jmeter.bat`, `jmeter.sh` and a few more, but no `jmeter.bat.sh`. So which did you try to change and how do you invoke jmeter? also setting `MaxNewSize` and `Xmx` to the same value doesn't make much sense (it's like not setting it at all)

Comment: thx @KirilS., how should the relation between `MaxNewSize` and `Xmx` be?

Comment: In most cases you don't need to specify MaxNewSize. You only need to worry about it if you found out (through testing) that allocated new size is sometimes too big. But in your case, seems you don't have such information, so just leave it alone

Comment: I'm running the app and also JMeter from two c4x.large boxes. Using the CMS garbage collector via `-XX:+UseConcMarkSweepGC` seems to help not to run into a Java memory overflow. But Java still seem to have around 9GB in usage when starting JMeter
`jmetert+  8616  0.0  0.0   4508  1764 pts/1    S+   11:05   0:00 /bin/sh ./jmeter.sh -n -t /home/jmetertestuser/TP_Login_Account_Project_Runbook.jmx ...
jmetert+  8642  214  8.3 9097220 684892 pts/1  Sl+  11:05   0:06 java -Xms512m -Xmx6144m -XX:NewSize=512m -XX:MaxNewSize=1024m -XX:+UseConcMarkSweepGC -jar ./ApacheJMeter.jar -n -t ...`

Answer (score 1):

If you are running `jmeter` startup script on Linux the syntax will be different, i.e:

```
HEAP="-Xms512m -Xmx6G"
```

as [SET command is something Windows-specific](https://ss64.com/nt/set.html)

Alternatively you can define `JVM_ARGS` environment variable value like:

```
JVM_ARGS="-server -Xms512m -Xmx6G" && export JVM_ARGS
```

this way you won't need to edit files and/or restart JMeter.

Finally, you can launch JMeter jar directly like:

```
java -server -Xms512m -Xmx6G -jar ApacheJMeter.jar
```

See the following reference material:

- [Tuning Java Virtual Machines (JVMs)](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E13222_01/wls/docs81/perform/JVMTuning.html)
- [JMeter Best Practices](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/best-practices.html)
- [9 Easy Solutions for a JMeter Load Test “Out of Memory” Failure](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/9-easy-solutions-jmeter-load-test-%E2%80%9Cout-memory%E2%80%9D-failure)